# Convert Oracle SQL trigger into a SQL Server trigger

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql

I have tried converting trigger written in Oracle to SQL Server triggers. But it does not allow to use table aliases and ":OLD" keyword in the query. Any idea how to do the correct conversion?

Oracle trigger:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_DEL_AM_LABELS   BEFORE DELETE on AM_LABELS
    FOR EACH ROW 
       BEGIN
         DELETE FROM AM_LABEL_URLS ALU WHERE ALU.LABEL_ID = :OLD.LABEL_ID;
       END;
```

Converted SQL Server trigger:

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER TRG_DEL_AM_LABELS 
ON AM_LABELS    
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM AM_LABEL_URLS ALU 
    WHERE ALU.LABEL_ID = :OLD.LABEL_ID;
END

CLOSE DELETED_CUR;
DEALLOCATE DELETED_CUR;
DELETE FROM AM_LABELS WHERE (.LABEL_ID;) IN (SELECT .LABEL_ID; FROM DELETED); 
;
```

These are the errors that popped up.

> Incorrect syntax near ':'.
>
> Incorrect syntax near 'ALU'.

But as it provided in documentation this query is valid to be used in SQL Server.

Comment: Not sure why you're typing `.LABEL_ID;` all around. It's `SELECT LABEL_ID FROM DELETED`, not `SELECT .LABEL_ID; FROM DELETED`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the DELETED table to access the old values:

> DML trigger statements use two special tables: the deleted table and
>   the inserted tables. SQL Server automatically creates and manages
>   these tables. You can use these temporary, memory-resident tables to
>   test the effects of certain data modifications and to set conditions
>   for DML trigger actions.
>
> The deleted table stores copies of the affected rows during DELETE and
>   UPDATE statements. During the execution of a DELETE or UPDATE
>   statement, rows are deleted from the trigger table and transferred to
>   the deleted table. The deleted table and the trigger table ordinarily
>   have no rows in common.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks I was able to resolve the Alies error. But still couldn't figure out that :old keyword error. @pifor Any idea how OLD can be replaced with deleted

Comment: @Chamindu It's explained in the answer and you already have it in your current code, although with random punctuation: `(SELECT LABEL_ID FROM DELETED)`.

Comment: So there is no need to use :OLD and instead should I use following query.        CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER TRG_DEL_AM_LABELS on AM_LABELS
  INSTEAD OF DELETE
     AS 
      BEGIN
        DELETE ALU FROM DELETED, AM_LABEL_URLS ALU WHERE ALU.LABEL_ID = DELETED.LABEL_ID;
      END
      CLOSE DELETED_CUR;
      DEALLOCATE DELETED_CUR;
      DELETE FROM AM_LABELS WHERE (LABEL_ID) IN (SELECT LABEL_ID FROM DELETED);
;

Comment: @Chamindu The key point to understand is that Oracle exposes values through a variable and SQL Server exposes values though a table.

Comment: Hi @ÁlvaroGonzález This seems to be working thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Hello One way to convert from Oracle to Sql Server could be this:

```
CREATE TABLE AM_LABELS (
    LABEL_ID int PRIMARY KEY,
    LABEL_NAME NVARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE AM_LABEL_URLS (
    URL_ID int PRIMARY KEY,
    LABEL_ID int,
    URL NVARCHAR(200),
    FOREIGN KEY (LABEL_ID) REFERENCES AM_LABELS(LABEL_ID)
);

INSERT INTO AM_LABELS (LABEL_ID, LABEL_NAME) VALUES (1, 'Label 1');
INSERT INTO AM_LABELS (LABEL_ID, LABEL_NAME) VALUES (2, 'Label 2');

INSERT INTO AM_LABEL_URLS (URL_ID, LABEL_ID, URL) VALUES (101, 1, 'www.john1.com');
INSERT INTO AM_LABEL_URLS (URL_ID, LABEL_ID, URL) VALUES (102, 1, 'www.john2.com');
INSERT INTO AM_LABEL_URLS (URL_ID, LABEL_ID, URL) VALUES (103, 2, 'www.john3.com');

select * from AM_LABELS
select * from AM_LABEL_URLS

CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER TRG_DEL_AM_LABELS
ON AM_LABELS
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM AM_LABEL_URLS WHERE LABEL_ID IN (SELECT deleted.LABEL_ID FROM deleted);
    DELETE FROM AM_LABELS WHERE LABEL_ID IN (SELECT deleted.LABEL_ID FROM deleted);
END;
GO
```

Test the trigger

```
DELETE FROM AM_LABELS 
WHERE LABEL_ID=2;
```

Hope it helps.